# Biking on via Appia Antica

Tags: public-transport, bicycles, rome

I'm going to stay in Rome for a few days and I would like to have a bike trip on via Appia Antica one day. I do not intend to have a tour, just rent a bike and ride on my own for a couple of hours.

What I need to find out is where can I find a bike rental service nearby and how do I get to the place from Ponte Sisto by public transport.

Thank you for information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that the number of bike rentals in Rome is limited.

I had a very good experience with this outfit:

http://www.freebiketoursrome.com

They start their bike tours next to a bike rental place that rents out good bikes:

http://www.romeforyou.net

Comment: Thank you! Though it appears that I have mistaken a bike rental with a tour in my question. Editing it now.

Comment: I was very happy with the bike I got from RomeForYou. If you get a tour with freebiketoursrome, they get you your bike from RomeForYou, but you can also just get a bike there, yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I used an app (not sure if I can name it here! "Citymapper") to get around Rome though I know Rome quite well. It will help you to find the best public transport options there to get from Ponté sisto to the Appian Way.
You buy tickets for buses in "Tabacchi" for 1,5 Euros each, and they are good for 100 minutes (you can change buses or from buses to Metro or vice -versa). Uber X does not exist there. You can easily rent a bike in center city and ride to the beginning of the Appian Way. Enjoy!

Comment: Yes you can mention the app here, just tell use whether you are just a user or involved with the company. (Both is acceptable but if you do not say it the community is likely to vote to delete for spam.)